# Can I sell Windows Phone 7 games on the marketplace from India?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketing

I am a developer from India working on a game in WP7. I need to know, can I sell my game in Windows phone apps marketplace or is it like Android market where only free/ad-based is allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's [absolutely OK](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join) to sell apps on Windows Phone marketplace. However you need to pay developer membership fee (which is 99$ per year), and submit your app (i.e. game) for certification.

I recommend you to check such info before starting working on a product in a future :-)